# Hover for class in two tables?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<table border=2>
    <tr class="here1 yes">
        <td>aaa1</td><td>bbb1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="here2 yes">
        <td>aaa2</td><td>bbb2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="here55 yes">
        <td>aaa3</td><td>bbb3</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<table border=2>
    <tr class="here1 yes">
        <td>ccc1</td><td>ddd1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="here2 yes">
        <td>ccc2</td><td>ddd2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="here55 yes">
        <td>ccc3</td><td>ddd3</td>
    </tr>
</table>


.yes:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/KzzW8/

The above table is generated with the following PHP:

```
 `<tr class="here<? echo $i ?> yes">`
```

I would like a mouseover on `TR.here1` to turn the contents of any `TR.here1` to RED where the subordinate `TD` is in the group: (aaa1, bbb1, ccc1, ddd1) regardless of which table it is in.

I believe I can use jQuery for this. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain in a clearer way exactly what you want to do?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: If i mouseover on class here1 then this class should be background-color: red in all class here1 on page (in my example in two tables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KzzW8/1/

```
$('tr').hover(function() {
    var cls = $(this).prop('class').match(/here\d+/);
    if (cls) {
        $('.' + cls).addClass('hover');
    }
}, function() {
    $('.yes.hover').removeClass('hover');
});​
```

So you on hover event get the `here*` class and apply class `.hover` to all the rows with the same class. On hover out - you remove all the additionally added classes

Comment: Probably friendlier in a real-world DOM with lots of other nodes to do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KzzW8/3/), but essentially still the same solution.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: indeed, the final decision depends on aims and current layout